# Syntax Error: unexpected keyword_do_block

Tags: ruby, foreach

I'm trying out some sample problems from a learn Ruby book and I'm getting a syntax error: unexpected keyword_do_block.

I have written similar code a billion times before and see nothing wrong (maybe I'm just daft tonight.) Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

The code:

```
temp = ["34","35","36","45","534","86","443","54","23","54","75","54","73"]

temp.each |e| do
  fahrenheit = (e * 9 / 5) + 32
  puts fahrenheit
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace to:

```
temp.each do |e|
  # ...
end
```

Also, you can't do math operations with String, remove all quotes from the array or use `e.to_i` within the block.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in your `each` block definition:

```
temp.each |e| do
```

should be:

```
temp.each do |e|
```

And, don't feel that you are daft. We *ALL* have times staring at code, when we can not see what is wrong. Having extra sets of eyes to find the problem is what pair-programming is all about.